# C++ segfault on pointer comparison

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have an std::vector of struct pointers, in which I would like to remove duplicate entries. However, I would like to compare one member of the struct instead of the pointer directly. When I do it the incorrect way (comparing the pointers directly) there is no segfault; the dupes simply don't get removed. However, when I access the element in question to compare, I get a segfault.

My first guess would be that the structs are invalid/freed, but I can put that member in a char array and print it to the debug log right before without an issue, so this does not seem to be the case.

If the structs are valid (which they both seem to be and should be; I calloc every one before adding it), then I don't know why comparing their members would cause any issue.

Anyways, here is my code:

struct definition:

```
 81         struct fp_node{
 82             Tile *t;
 83             unsigned int g;
 84             unsigned int h;
 85             unsigned int score;
 86             struct fp_node *parent;
 87             char type;
 88         };
```

Accessing that member without issue

```
279 #ifdef DEBUG
280         for(unsigned int i = 0; i < open_list.size(); ++i){
281             char address[11];
282             snprintf(address, 11, "0x%08x", open_list[i]->t);
283             gui::log("Open list entry " + std::to_string(i) + ": " + std::string(address));
284         }
285 #endif
```

dupe filtering causing the issue:

```
291         for(unsigned int i = 0; i < open_list.size(); ++i){
292             for(unsigned int j = 0; j < open_list.size(); ++j){
293                 if(i == j) continue;
294                 if(open_list[i]->t == open_list[j]->t){
295                     free(open_list[j]);
296                     open_list.erase(open_list.begin() + j);
297                     i -= 1;
298                     j -= 1;
299                 }
300             }
301             
302             for(unsigned int j = 0; j < closed_list.size(); ++j){
303                 if(open_list[i] != closed_list[j]) continue;
304                 free(open_list[i]);
305                 open_list.erase(open_list.begin() + i);
306                 i -= 1;
307             }
308         }
```

Notice that in the first `j` for loop, I access the t member of the struct. This causes the segfault. The second `j` loop does simply compares the pointers. It doesn't segfault but it isn't what I want.

I tried accessing methods from the tile class, but those segfault as well, so I do think the memory is somehow being freed automatically in the meantime. I don't know why though, as everything is on the heap except for the vectors themselves, which are in a larger scope and shouldn't die.

However, when I try to access the member in only one part of the comparison (`if((Tile *)open_list[i] == open_list[j]->t)`), I don't get a segfault; same with the other side.

I'm completely lost here, can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: `fp_node` contains a pointer, but lack the tools to manage the pointer. This leaves it vulnerable to having two copies pointing to the same memory. No way to tell from what's been given to tell if this, or anything else, is the problem.

Comment: Too many possibilities for the cause here.   You need to provide an [mcve].   Voted to close accordingly.   You probably need to check that pointers in the vector are valid before dereferencing them (e.g. accessing their members).

Comment: @user4581301 That's the reason I want to do this in the first place. This _is_ the tool to manage the pointer.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable way to do things. Still don't have an answer for you, but here is something to try. When you `malloc` or  `free`, dump the address  and index to a file, then read through the file looking for duplicates. Index won't be too useful, but you never know. Only other suggestion is make absolutely certain that `open_list` or whatever contains it never gets copied.

Comment: you need to actually post code that can be compiled and run to reproduce you error, as described here: [mcve]

Comment: `j` should start at `i + 1` (and care should be taken that j doesn't go past the end of the vector). Also, why do you decrement `i` when you erase the item at `j`? Think of what happens if you find a dupe of `open_list[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the sleepy in my eyes is not making my mind see spots, but something jumps out at me.

Hard to say for sure as you don't say how open_list is allocated. Since open_list is released by free() I'm going to assume it is a simple pointer allocated by malloc() or calloc() and these are C functions. Never tried mixing malloc() and size(), or new() and free(), but I would fear that array size reported by from open_list.size() would not change under free().

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/size/

Comment: open_list is on the stack. The structs inside are calloced and freed.